# Java - Access values in generic enum

Tags: java, generics, enums, casting

Is there a way to use the "values()" method from a generic enum ?

```
public class TCP_Message<T extends Enum<T>> {

    public T anEnum;

    public void doSomething() {
        anEnum = T.values().values[0];
    }
}
```

this code does not allow me to access .values().

Comment: No. You'll need to provide the class of the enum.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-a-class-instance-of-generics-type-t

Comment: Possibly related [Iterate enum values using java generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2205891)

Comment: If you have the `Class` object of the enum -- as you'll probably need -- you can use `getEnumConstants()`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for your answers, it works fine now.